# Google Webmaster can't recognize redirect

Tags: google-search-console, 301-redirect, fetch-as-google

I add a 301 redirect for a URL listed in the "Crawl Error" but when I try to fetch it on the Webmaster Tools it is still "Not Found".

When you type the URL on the address bar the redirect is ok. I waited for 30 mins then fetch again but still the status is "Not Found". What could be the problem?

Comment: Is the 301 redirect in the .htaccess file and have you submitted an updated sitemap to Google?

Comment: @Nucleotide a plugin in wordpress that manage the 301 redirect and I didn't submitted any sitemap.

Comment: do you have any user recognition based on ip? it could be that your system shows to google something different as to your browser

Comment: @Evgeniy some of the URL I Redirected can recognize by google webmaster. I will try it on the other connection.

Comment: @Nucleotide Thanks for you help. The issue is fix now. I waited it for the next day then tried to fetch again and the redirect is recognize now. Thanks again and have a great day.

Comment: @Evgeniy Thank you for you time to read and answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

For all, who means to be affected from the same issue: Google, specially on actualization of the web gui of search console, needs time. It fetchs data from different data centers, caches etc. so it could happen, that your changes aren't shown in the search console for a pretty long piece of time. But, the solution is: after you checked your implementations and are sure, they are correct, just wait.